# Typo in Wilmott's Forward rate formula?

Tags: interest-rates, yield-curve, forward-rate

I am going through the 2nd edition of Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance, and came across the following,

[image]

Shouldn't the last equality be

$$
F(t;T) = y(t;T) + \color{red}{(T-t)}\frac{\partial y}{\partial T}
$$

or maybe I am missing something simple?

Also, is anyone aware is there is an erratum online?

Comment: Looks like you’re right

Comment: Yes, an obvious error, but I can understand the frustration when you are new to the subject and encounter typos. There is always the unpleasant feeling that one might have missed something.

Comment: It's a typo I agree